# Post not deleting, server error 500 in laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

Please what am I doing wrong, Paymentdetails refuse to delete instead, its loading server error.There's something wrong with my code.

**This is my controller**

```
public function destroy(Paymentdetail $paymentdetail)
    {
        //  dd($id);

        if(Auth::user()->role_id == '1'){
           
                $this->paymentdetails->delete($paymentdetail->id);

                event(new Deleted($paymentdetail));
            return redirect()->route('paymentdetails.index')
            ->withSuccess(__('Payment details deleted successfully.'));
           }
           else{
               return redirect()->back()
               ->withErrors(__('Sorry! You Are Not Authorized To Delete Payment Details.'));
           }
        
        
    }
```

**index.blade**

```
                    <a href="{{ route('paymentdetails.edit', $paymentdetail) }}"
                                class="btn btn-icon edit"
                                title="@lang('Edit Paymentdetail')"
                                data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top">
                                    <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                                </a>

                                <a href="{{ route('paymentdetails.destroy', $paymentdetail) }}"
                                class="btn btn-icon"
                                title="@lang('Delete Paymentdetail')"
                                data-toggle="tooltip"
                                data-placement="top"
                                data-method="DELETE"
                                data-confirm-title="@lang('Please Confirm')"
                                data-confirm-text="@lang('Are you sure that you want to delete this payment details?')"
                                data-confirm-delete="@lang('Yes, delete details!')">
                                    <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
                                </a></a>
```

Comment: *I guess there's something wrong with my code* without more information it's very difficult for us to guess what is wrong with your code as well.

Comment: `$this->paymentdetails->delete($paymentdetail->id);` seems super confusing,  why not `$paymentdetail->delete()`?

Comment: @NoOorZ24 you mean something like this: `$paymentdetails->delete($paymentdetail->id);`

Comment: @NigelRen "guess" removed from the question

Comment: @Olu-Stephen No! `$paymentdetail` is instance of `Paymentdetail` and it extends Laravel `Model`. If it's instance of model it know how to find itself in DB therefore you can call `$paymentdetail->delete()` and instance will delete itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moved my answer from comments"

```
$this->paymentdetails->delete($paymentdetail->id);
```

seems over-engineered and confusing

`$paymentdetail` is instance of `Paymentdetail` and it extends Laravel `Model`. As it is instance of model - it knows how to find itself in DB therefore you can call

```
$paymentdetail->delete();
```

and instance will delete itself

Answer (score 0):

1. First check your request method,it should be Get method.
2. iF method is Get then is it redirecting to given function?
3. You should on debug mod of laravel which gives you proper error.
4. Another thing check is user authenticated?